# runOnUiThread not executed right after calling

Tags: java, android

I try to make a progressbar on a button click. the progressbar is only visible after everything else is procesed.

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } });
```

Can I force the UI thread to join or something like that?

EDIT: Complete onClick code

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == etLocation){
        etLocation.setText("");

    }
    if (view == btnGo){

        //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } });

        Thread buttonpress = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                buttonGo();
            }
        });


        buttonpress.run();


    }
    if (view == datePicker){
        new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: why? just simply call setvisibility

Comment: What does "after everything else is procesed" mean? "Can I force the UI thread to join or something like that?" -- no. Your `Runnable` should run when the main application thread gets control. If your `Runnable` is *not* running, most likely that is because you are tying up your main application thread.

Comment: does not work. i executes the other code first. and i want the progressbar shown the exact moment it is called.

Comment: after the set visibility i create an other thread and let this thread handle the rest

Answer (score 1):

runOnUiThread is async. Looking through your code, I see an easy fix to it too:

```
    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    Thread buttonpress = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            buttonGo();
        }
    });
    //Move runOnUiThread down. The thread above will not start doing its thing until you tell it to run
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonpress.run();//TO HERE. Now the progressbar will be initialized, THEN the thread will start
        } });


    //buttonpress.run(); MOVE THIS
```

What I basically did was move runOnUiThread down, so it can access the ButtonPress thread.

Then, after the progressBar is visible, you run the thread.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread is intentionally asynchronous. The job of the application layer is to tell the UI thread **what** to do, **not when** to do it.

If your application logic depends on the UI updating, then you should consider your application logic to be too tightly coupled anyway.

Comment: i want the progress bar shown while it is loading. so i start it the moment the button is presed. I have no idea how i could handle this different.

Comment: well, lets consider you force showing your download bar (however we do that), your performance would drop for small elements. Image a file that is so small, that it is actually faster to ask for showing the progress bar and ask to hide it again once things are done. Your UI might be busy with other drawing events until the download finished. In such a scenario the UI will be asked update the screen and it sees "well there is actually nothing new here".

Comment: Additionally, screens have a delay between redrawing (50 to 60Hz displays), so there are roughly 20ms delays between the drawing of frames. So if updating the screen is not at the same nanosecond, don't worry. The screen doesn't get updated for another 19.999... ms

Doing things asynchronously is good enough - don't worry about the small delay between "please update UI" and the actual rendering of the UI.

Comment: With an imageView the same thing happens